# Indexes with $in or $or

Tags: mongodb, indexing

My document structure is something like this

```
{
    _id: "id1",
    field1: "val1",
    field2: "val2",
    outcome: "ABC"
}
```

I have created index on outcome field. I have to find all documents with `{outcome:"ABC"}` or `{outcome:"XYZ"}` only. There is no major difference in query execution time if i use `$or` or `$in`. e.g

```
db.coll.find({$or:[{outcome:"ABC"},{outcome:"XYZ"}]}); 
db.coll.find({outcome:{$in:["ABC","XYZ"]}});
```

Which operator should i use `$or` or `$in` in this case? And why? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `db.coll.find({ //your query }).explain("executionStats")` and see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-versus-in)

> When using `$or` with `<expressions>` that are equality checks for the value of the same field, use the `$in` operator instead of the `$or` operator.
>
> For example, to select all documents in the inventory collection where the quantity field value equals either `20` or `50`, use the `$in` operator:
>
> ```
> db.inventory.find ( { quantity: { $in: [20, 50] } } )
> ```

So in your case it is better to use

```
db.coll.find({outcome:{$in:["ABC","XYZ"]}});
```